# Why does OraNet.dcu have no corresponding .pas file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, devart, odac

I have a related post - [Assertion failure in DBAccess.pas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496878/assertion-failure-in-dbaccess-pas) but thought this was worth asking separately.

We are licensed for the full source-code release of DevArt ODAC but have been experiencing tremendous difficulties performing an upgrade.  In the course of investigating this I have noticed that there is no .pas file for OraNet.dcu.

This is making it difficult to establish what the cause of our difficulties is as we cannot fully debug the code.

Also - what is this unit?  From its name and the directives in the code it would be reasonable to suppose it is a .NET required unit - not something we are interested in.

Comment: @devart - I have also noticed that Delphi refuses to close when the packages are installed - is this a known issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the Direct DB connection mode implemented in the OraNet.dcu module, and we don't distribute the source code of this module, this limitation is specified at our [website](http://www.devart.com/odac/ordering.html) (the reference at the bottom of the page). If you don't use the Direct mode, and work via the Oracle client (the OCI mode), you can specify DEFINE NONET in your project settings, in this case, the Direct mode will be unavailable, and this module won't be used.

Comment: To my understanding, using Oracle Instant Client dlls is a much better option than using this oci8 based dcu, even if will use more disk space. OIC has tremendous performance a nd unleash both Oracle and Odac great potential.

Comment: In my case I have a large estate to upgrade.  The cost of additional testing prohibits a root and branch change.

Answer (score 0):

The client usage (even Oracle Instant Client) really allows using more features, than our Direct mode, but the Direct mode even surpasses OCI by performance in some cases. Besides, the Direct mode significantly simplifies application deployment and decreases the application size on disk due to the fact that there is no need to supply and deploy additional libraries, and set additional registry parameters and environment variables. The Direct mode also allows application deployment to systems, for which there are no native Oracle clients, for example, iOS. Choosing of the way of working with the DB (Direct or OCI) depends on developer and tasks resolved by each particular application. As it was mentioned above, if the Direct mode is not used, additional module plugging can be disabled by setting DEFINE NONET

Comment: It is beginning to look as though `$(DEFINE NONET)` is the answer for us. The existing software is OCI, as I understand it, and I have not yet been able to replicate the problem in a small app suitable for sharing.  I am still interested in running this to ground if I can - Direct Oracle Access would be very sweet for us if it can be achieved.

Comment: Sorry but that last comment of mine was mis-informed.  `NONET` makes no difference to the way the software behaves.

Comment: In order for your application not to use the OraNet.dcu module, you should add NONET in the Conditional Defines parameter of your project settings.In this case, the OraNet module won't be included to the project on compilation (you can delete this module). If you want to retrieve another behaviour, please describe it in more details.

P.S. The selection of connection type is controlled by the OraSession.Options.Direct option (True -Direct, False - OCI (by default))

Comment: Yes - understood.  By 'Makes no difference' I really meant 'does not help with my problem'.